# Create pop-up message on javascript when mouseover on image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating a website introducing Thai food. I would like to create a message box when my mouse is anywhere on the image.

HTML:

```
<th><h1>Must-Eats!<h1>
<h2> You cannot say you have been to Thailand if you have not tried these amazing food! </h2>
<p id="food"></p>
<img src="mangorice.jpg"style="width:400px;height:250px;" alt="MANGORICE" title="mangorice"></a>
<img src="icecream.jpg"style="width:400px;height:250px;" alt="ICECREAM" title="icecream"></a>
<img src="cake.jpg"style="width:400px;height:250px;" alt="CAKE" title="cake"></a>
<img src="tomyum.jpg"style="width:400px;height:250px;" alt="TOMYUM" title="tomyum"></a>
<img src="thainoodle.jpg"style="width:400px;height:250px;" alt="PADTHAI" title="padthai"></a>
<img src="mooping.jpg"style="width:400px;height:250px;" alt="MOOPING" title="mooping"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: did you mean tooltip on mouseover?

Comment: what have you tried so far? any ideas of what you want to end result make look like?

Comment: Do you want a tooltip or an alert message?

Comment: If you want an alert box: `Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img')).forEach(function(el) { el.onmouseover = function() { alert('You hovered over an image named' + el.attributes.title.textContent); }; });`

Comment: your html is wrong. you start with an `th` tag and then you end with a closing `</div>` tag. If you use HTML5, you can check out my bootstrap solution below.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple to add tooltip.

Just include JQuery UI library and add following JQuery with JQuery library.

```
$(function() {
    $( document ).tooltip();
  });
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e32gzmv5/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use tooltip for pop up on mouse on over.

[Check this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Answer (score 0):

### The native solution

The easiest way to show a single line of text on mouseover is to use the `title` attribute:

```
<img src="my_pic.jpg" title="That's me when I was 5!" alt="me at 5">
```

Anyhow, for nicer formatting and better effects you can use either the [jQuery tooltips](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

### Bootstrap solutions

Here I wrote some example code for the bootstrap [tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips) and [popovers](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZQazKp

*Don't forget that in order to use the bootstrap's functionality, you need to include both the Bootstrap CSS and JS.*

You can do so, by adding these lines to your `<head>` element:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Or refer to [this document](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) for more options.